# Linq grouping query to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Trying to return a Linq group by query into a DataTable.  Getting the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The I am querying a DataTable named Vendors where the data would be as follows:

```
Vendor         Name 
654797         Lowes
897913         Home Depot
800654         Waffle House
```

The Vendor is stored as char(6) in the DB and name as char as well... don't ask me why, I just work here :)

```
    DataTable VendorsDT = New DataTable();
    DataColumn VenName = VendorsDT.Columns.Add("Name", typeof (string));
    DataColumn VenCode = VendorsDT.Columns.Add("Vendor", typeof(string));


    IEnumerable<DataRow> Vendors = from row in alertsDT.AsEnumerable()
                                   group row by new { Name = row.Field<string>("Name"), Vendor = row.Field<string>("Vendor") } into z
                                   select new
                                   {
                                        Name = z.Key.Name,
                                        Vendor = z.Key.Vendor,                        

                                   };



    VendorsDT = Vendors.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work, as you are projecting your original query of `alertsDT` into an anonymous type, which would not be able to be referenced by your `IEnumerable<DataRow> Vendor` variable, because your query is *not* a sequence of DataRows.

Given that you are performing a grouping, and that you have also already set up your `VendorsDT` table with the desired columns, the path of least resistance is to fix your `Vendor` variable type (use `var` for type inference) and then loop over the result to populate your second table.

```
var Vendors = /* your unchanged query omitted */ 

foreach (var item in Vendors) 
{
    VendorsDT.Rows.Add(item.Name, item.Vendor);
}
```

As a note, I've used your variable names, although it is convention in C# to use lower case letters to start local variable names, with upper case typically left for method names, properties, etc. So you would favor `vendors` over `Vendors` and `vendorsDT` (or `vendorsTable`) over `VendorsDT`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i've not done any of this in years.  Your solution worked and the additional formatting tips are much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

This is a more linq way of doing

```
  var query = from row in alertsDT.AsEnumerable()
                      group row by new { Name = row.Field<string>("Name"), Vendor = row.Field<string>("Vendor") } into z
                      select new 
                      {
                        Name=  z.Key.Name,
                        Vendor=  z.Key.Vendor,

                      };
        VendorsDT = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Here define the extension method 'CopyToDataTable()' as specified in the following [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) article.

The CopyToDataTable method takes the results of a query and copies the data into a DataTable, which can then be used for data binding. The CopyToDataTable methods, however, only operate on an IEnumerable source where the generic parameter T is of type DataRow. Although this is useful, it does not allow tables to be created from a sequence of scalar types, from queries that project anonymous types, or from queries that perform table joins.

Comment: this query result can't do CopyToDataTable()