# Linq Datatable subset using group by and having count >1

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Need some help with Linq.

I have a Datatable which looks like the following
[I just have the W_text with me to search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgF4V.png)

Using the above datatable, I would like to extract the subset of rows having the following result

[The key to search is "First Employee"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzMs4.png)

So as you can see, I want to get a subset of those rows which have W_Text values as "First" and "Employee" but having the same l_id.

In DB terms, this would be a Select * from Table 1 where W_Text in ('First','Employee') group by l_id having l_id > 1 (or something like this).

How do i achieve this in C# using a datatable?

I tried playing around with the following code, but this gives me the whole datatable with other rows as well. I am not sure how to use group by and having clause. I would appeciate if someone can help me in this regard.

```
var results = from myRow in dtResult.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "First" ||
                    myRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "Employee"
              select myRow;

dtCopy = results.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following:

```
      List<string> wTextFilter = new List<string>();
        wTextFilter.Add("First");
        wTextFilter.Add("Employee");

        // Get all Id's that satisfy all conditions:            
        List<int> results = dt.AsEnumerable()
            // Get all Id's:
            .Select(dataRow => dataRow.Field<int>("l_id"))
            // Filter the Id's : 
            .Where(id =>
                // the Id should be greater than one.
                    id > 1   &&
                    // check if all W_Text entries has a record in the datatable with the same Id.
                    wTextFilter.All(W_Text => dt.AsEnumerable().Any(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == W_Text && dataRow.Field<int>("l_id") == id)))
                    .Distinct().ToList();

        // Get all datatable rows filtered by the list of Id's.
        DataTable dtCopy = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dataRow => results.Contains((dataRow.Field<int>("l_id")))).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks Abdhulla. This is also giving me a dataset with all the occurrences of "First" and "Employee". I want just that Dataset where both "First" and "Employee" both are there for the same l_id, in other words where count (l_id) is >1

Comment: Check the code snippet shown above after the new edit.

Comment: Worked Brilliantly!
Thanks a lot Abdhullah. Really appreciate your response.

Can you please help me understand how the code works? I am having a hard time understanding Linq especially with these aggregate functions.

Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome :). I have added some comments to the code above.

Comment: Have a follow up question sir -

Is it possible to dynamically build this query? For e.g here my input string was "First Employee" so the query had "First" and "Employee". Say tomorrow I have something called as "First Employee Salary" then i need to search all 3 words. 

I tried playing around to append dynamically but it is failing. Any help again would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks again Abdhulla. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use like this as shown

```
var results = (from myRow in dtResult.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "First" ||
              myRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "Employee"
              select myRow ).ToLookup(item => item.Field<string>("l_id"));
```

OR

```
var results = (from myRow in dtResult.AsEnumerable()
               where myRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "First" ||
               myRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "Employee"
               select myRow).GroupBy(item => item.Field<string>("l_id")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Vara. 
Although this is now showing the results count as the same as the subset, but I am unable to do the copy to Datatable. Can you please tell me how to traverse trough the results variable? I am also looking up as we speak, but your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: sorry for the delay, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566246/linq-grouping-query-to-datatable

Comment: Thanks again Vara, however your response is returning all the l_id values which contain the text "First" or "Employee". I just want that unique l_id which contains both "First" and "Employee". Thanks again